# Python saying variable is non type when it is an int

Tags: python, int, syntax-error, try-catch

I am writing this program for my class and whenever I run it inputting only integers it runs fine. As soon as I input a string and trigger the try exception block, it runs the function again but it says that the variable ticket is a non type when it should be an integer and i'm not sure why this is happening.

Problem Function:

```
def asktickets():
    # Notifies user that data inputed was wrong and explains why then lets you try again
    asktickets2 = input('Enter the number of violations 0 or more: ')
    try:
        tickets = int(asktickets2)
        if tickets < 0:
            continue2 = input(
                'Invalid input: The number of violations must be more than 0. Please click enter to try again.')
            asktickets()
        else:
            return int(tickets)
    except ValueError:
        continue2 = input(
            'Invalid input: The number of violations must be more than 0. Please click enter to try again.')
        asktickets2 = 0;
        tickets = 0
        asktickets()
```

Full Code (the error is happening with the variable tickets in the main when it is passed into the RiskCode() method but only if you enter a string then an integer first when running the program:

```
# File Name: Shepherd_Project 1.py
def askage():
    # Asks user for age
    askage2 = input('Please enter age of client (age must be between 16-105): ')
    try:
        age = int(askage2)
        if age <= 15 or age > 105:
            continue1 = input('Invalid input: Age range must be between 16-105. Please click enter to try again.')
            askage()
        else:
            return age
    except ValueError:
        continue2 = input(
            'Invalid input: The age range must be between 16-105. Please click enter to try again.')
        askage()


def asktickets():
    # Notifies user that data inputed was wrong and explains why then lets you try again
    asktickets2 = input('Enter the number of violations 0 or more: ')
    try:
        tickets = int(asktickets2)
        if tickets < 0:
            continue2 = input(
                'Invalid input: The number of violations must be more than 0. Please click enter to try again.')
            asktickets()
        else:
            return int(tickets)
    except ValueError:
        continue2 = input(
            'Invalid input: The number of violations must be more than 0. Please click enter to try again.')
        asktickets2 = 0;
        tickets = 0
        asktickets()


def RiskCode(tickets):
    # Assigns risk code based on number of tickets
    tickets2 = int(tickets)
    if tickets2 == 0:
        risk = 'No'
    elif tickets2 == 1:
        risk = 'Low'
    elif tickets2 == 2 or tickets2 == 3:
        risk = 'Moderate'
    elif tickets2 >= 4:
        risk = 'High'
    return risk


def price(tickets, age):
    # calculates the estimated price of insurance based on age and number of tickets
    if tickets == 0 and age < 25:
        ammount = '$325'
    elif tickets == 0 and age >= 25:
        ammount = '$275'
    elif tickets == 1 and age < 25:
        ammount = '$380'
    elif tickets == 1 and age >= 25:
        ammount = '$315'
    elif tickets == 2 and age < 25:
        ammount = '$405'
    elif tickets == 2 and age >= 25:
        ammount = '$365'
    elif tickets == 3 and age < 25:
        ammount = '$450'
    elif tickets == 3 and age >= 25:
        ammount = '$390'
    elif tickets >= 4 and age < 25:
        ammount = '$480'
    elif tickets >= 4 and age >= 25:
        ammount = '$410'
    return ammount


def ProgStatus():
    # Changes program status to end program
    status = 'active'
    user_status = input('Type “y” to begin or “x” to end program. ')
    # if user enters X program ends
    if user_status == 'x':
        status = 'end'
        print('Program Ended')
    # if user enters y program restarts
    elif user_status == 'y':
        status = 'active'
    # if user types any thing other than Y or X user is asked to try again
    else:
        continue3 = input('Invalid input: You have typed a letter other than "y" or "x". Click enter to try again.')
        ProgStatus()
    # returns value to main()
    return status


def main():
    statusLocal = ProgStatus()
    while statusLocal == 'active':
        # Details what program does
        print("This program will calculate the estimated price of insurance.")
        # Asks user for name
        name = input('Please enter the name of client: ')
        # sets the age variable
        age = askage()
        # sets the risk variable
        tickets = asktickets()
        risk = RiskCode(tickets)
        # sets the estimated price of the insurance
        InsuranceAmmount = price(tickets, age)
        print(name, ',(', age, ') is a', risk, 'risk driver, your insurance will cost', InsuranceAmmount, '.')
        statusLocal = ProgStatus()


main()
```

Console input and output with error:

```
Type “y” to begin or “x” to end program. y
This program will calculate the estimated price of insurance.
Please enter the name of client: mark
Please enter age of client (age must be between 16-105): 18
Enter the number of violations 0 or more: h
Invalid input: The number of violations must be more than 0. Please click enter to try again.
Enter the number of violations 0 or more: 6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/pipere/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/main.py", line 113, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/pipere/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/main.py", line 106, in main
    risk = RiskCode(tickets)
  File "C:/Users/pipere/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/main.py", line 39, in RiskCode
    tickets2 = int(tickets)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Your response is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you recurse in `askage`, you need to `return` the result. Change the code here,

```
if age <= 15 or age > 105:
    continue1 = input('Invalid input: Age range must be between 16-105. Please click enter to try again.')
    askage()
```

to something like

```
if age <= 15 or age > 105:
    continue1 = input('Invalid input: Age range must be between 16-105. Please click enter to try again.')
    return askage()
```

Likewise, when you recurse with `asktickets()` be sure to

```
return asktickets()
```

**And** in `ProgStatus()`

```
return ProgStatus()
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to `return asktickets()` not just call the function

```
def asktickets():
    # Notifies user that data inputed was wrong and explains why then lets you try again
    asktickets2 = input('Enter the number of violations 0 or more: ')
    try:
        tickets = int(asktickets2)
        if tickets < 0:
            continue2 = input(
                'Invalid input: The number of violations must be more than 0. Please click enter to try again.')
            asktickets()
        else:
            return int(tickets)
    except ValueError:
        continue2 = input(
            'Invalid input: The number of violations must be more than 0. Please click enter to try again.')
        asktickets2 = 0;
        tickets = 0
        return asktickets() #return function not just call
```

> ```
> Type “y” to begin or “x” to end program. y
> This program will calculate the estimated price of insurance.
> Please enter the name of client: mark
> Please enter age of client (age must be between 16-105): 18
> Enter the number of violations 0 or more: k
> Invalid input: The number of violations must be more than 0. Please click enter to try again.
> Enter the number of violations 0 or more: 6
> mark ,( 18 ) is a High risk driver, your insurance will cost $480 .
> ```

Comment: @cliffdog no problem, the other user is very well knowledgeable, his answer may even be more informative!